# Why does Couchbase Server 2.0 fall over when I add a second bucket?

Tags: nosql, couchbase

Can anyone confrim if this is just me or a bug in the developer preview of Couchbase 2.0 Server.

Scenario:

I install Couchbase server on a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM. All starts up ok and works fine.
When I add a second bucket, the bucket is added, but straight after the servers all go into a pending state and are unresponsive.

All I can do is reinstall the product to get out of this situation.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the same question is being tracked over on our forums and we are working on it: http://www.couchbase.org/forums/thread/create-new-data-bucket-failed